# Educational resources commonly address slant asymptotes. Why not general polynomial asymptotes?

Tags: secondary-education, mathematical-pedagogy, terminology, precalculus, functions

Back in 2018, I wrote a [post](https://www.justinmath.com/graphing-rational-functions-with-slant-and-polynomial-asymptotes/) about asymptotes of rational functions in which I addressed not only horizontal and slant/oblique asymptotes, but also the general case of "polynomial asymptotes." Fast-forward over 5 years later, the post gets plenty of traffic from the query "polynomial asymptote" because apparently polynomial asymptotes are not covered anywhere else! (Below is a snippet of the post that describes what I mean by "polynomial asymptotes.")

[image]

It strikes me as really weird that polynomial asymptotes are not covered elsewhere. They are a natural generalization of slant asymptotes, they help develop intuition about why graphs of rational functions look like they do, and they don't require any more advanced computation techniques –- it's still just polynomial long division (or even synthetic division if your divisor is linear).

**My questions:**

**1. Why are polynomial asymptotes not normally covered along by resources that teach slant asymptotes?**

**2. I can't find the phrase "polynomial asymptote" elsewhere on the web. I tried searching images too and don't see any other images of graphs illustrating this concept. Is the phrase "polynomial asymptote" truly nonexistent outside of this post? If so, why? If not, what other resource(s) mention it?**

My intention with these questions is less about critiquing curriculum and more about just trying to make sense of a phenomenon that strikes me as really weird.

---

**Falsified Hypotheses**

Below are some explanations that sounded initially sounded promising, but upon deeper analysis, turned out not to be true.

- *Maybe it's because people just refer to "slant asymptotes" in the most general sense, not just lines but also polynomials of degree greater than 1.* False. Resources that talk about slant asymptotes generally say that "a slant asymptote occurs when the degree of the numerator is 1 more than the degree of the denominator." So I don't think that's the case.
- *Maybe it's because polynomial asymptotes are just one special case in [general asymptotic analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis).* False. In the context of rational functions, polynomial asymptotes fully describe the general case -- they're not just a special case. And by this reasoning, it should also be uncommon to address slant/oblique asymptotes, which are actually special cases.

**Non-Falsified but Non-Definitive Hypotheses**

Below are explanations that sound promising and have not been falsified, but have not accumulated enough evidence to be considered definitively "the answer."

- *It's less useful in practice than it is in theory. In practice, sketching a general polynomial is not that much easier than sketching a general rational function. And often we only care about behavior for large x, which we can easily determine by just dividing the highest-degree term of the numerator by the highest-degree term of the denominator.* True, but not definitive because educational resources often cover other things that are less useful in practice than they are in theory.

**Update:** The accepted answer makes the above hypothesis definitive by pointing out that there's actually not much theory that builds on polynomial asymptotes, whereas there is more theory that builds on related topics of little-o and big-O notation. So if you start with polynomial asymptotes and follow that line of thought deeper, you end up at little-o and big-O notation, for which polynomial asymptotes are not actually a prerequisite.

Comment: As a point of reference, I wasn't taught, nor have taught, slant/oblique asymptotes. If I had been taught them, it would have been about 45 years ago. Horizontal asymptotes have quite few ties to applications; for instance, equilibria in DEs. The nearest thing I know to polynomial asymptotes are limit cycles and transients in oscillatory systems. -- It disappointed me to figure out later that functions that are asymptotic to each other are not "asymptote-ic" to each other. (For instance, if $y=ax+b$ is an asymptote of $y=f(x)$ then $\lim f(x)/(ax+c)=1$ at infinity for any $c$.)

Comment: *I can't find the phrase "polynomial asymptote" elsewhere on the web.* --- See my first comment to [How do we know that a rational function has at most 1 slant asymptote?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4435969/13130) (and my comment to the answer),  [this 22 May 2003 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/S7X-C-FglaQ/m/Xhlkm6ii3dMJ) and [these google hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22polynomial+asymptote%22&filter=0). I probably used the term often in the ap-calculus discussion group when it was hosted by Math Forum, but those posts are no longer available.

Comment: FYI, your graphs/examples from that 2018 web page are very similar to many worksheets and quiz/test solutions I wrote in the late 1990s for the 3 years I taught [here](https://www.lsmsa.edu/). Some of those used to be archived at Math Forum, early 2010s when they began allowing attachments to posts and before they were ended by NCTM (who had taken over them sometime in the mid 2010s), but unless any were captured (and can be found) by the Way Back Machine, probably none of them exist online anymore. By the way, I'm not saying the examples were the same, but rather the spirit is very similar.

Comment: Thanks @DaveLRenfro, this is interesting -- I see that the phrase "nonlinear asymptote" turns up a couple hits (though it's still surprising how few!). Given that you wrote a bit about this and even taught it in classes decades ago, did you ever get a sense of why it's barely covered elsewhere? For instance, in your experience, are people "resistant" to it for some reason?

Comment: I don't know why it's hardly taught. It provides reinforcement long division practice as well as showing an application that students can appreciate, and you often get neat looking graphs when graphing by calculator or computer algebra. I've seen this sometimes covered in college algebra and precalculus texts, but with other terms (I listed some of these terms in another comment at the SE link I gave). I don't think I've ever seen the term "polynomial asymptote" used before I made up the name, but surely others must have used the term because it seems such an obvious term.

Comment: It seems the only term I mentioned is "nonlinear asymptote". I remember seeing a rational function with a cubic asymptote in a college algebra/precalculus text I taught from around 1993-1996, but I can't find it now for some reason. In fact, the graph I'm thinking of (I remember how it looked) isn't in any of the books I looked through just now on my bookshelves, but I did find two that bring up the notion without naming it: Burzynski/Ellis/Lodi, "Precalculus with Trigonometry" (1995; worked example on pp. 267-270) AND Cohen, "College Algebra" (4th ed. 1996, exercise 9 on pp. 343-344).

Comment: If no one writes up a reasonably decent answer, in a few days for an answer I'll try to assemble/revise my comments along with some guesses and observations that I can think of. I'm a bit busy today, and probably shouldn't have spent as much time tracking down/commenting as I've done, but at least in this case I'm not just "talking to myself" (so to speak).

Comment: I think the phrase would be "end behavior" of a rational function. See for instance: https://study.com/skill/learn/how-to-determine-the-end-behavior-of-a-rational-function-explanation.html

Comment: Perhaps k-12 or typical undergrad texts don't mention more complicated asymptotics, but it's "certainly a thing" in the larger world of mathematics. Keyword/phrase "asymptotic expansions". And/but, yes, I'd not be optimistic about imparting these ideas to college freshmen who didn't want to be in the room in the first place. :)

Comment: @Aeryk: Despite what the web page you linked to says, usually (unless textbooks have changed on this issue in the last 15-20 years), "end behavior" only refers to the dominant term (= leading term) of the quotient, not the entire quotient. As you zoom out, the graph of the rational function will **appear** to get closer and closer to the end behavior's graph, but usually their actual vertical distance apart becomes arbitrarily large (i.e. relative vertical distance approaches zero, but actual vertical distance doesn't have to and in fact can approach infinity as $|x| \rightarrow \infty).$

Comment: @DaveLRenfro True. I think textbooks are a little behind in this. What I use in class is that there are different levels of describing the end behavior, e.g. positively divergent, like x^2, asymptotic to 3x^2+4x-5. This corresponds to the higher-level ideas of limit at infinity, (roughly) Big Oh, and Asymptotics

Comment: I think it's the nature of the subject, so many students struggling to stay above water. I don't even try slant asymptotes with the College Algebra crowd. If I can get them to deal correctly with horizontal asymptotes then I count it a blessing. Of course, we ought to teach polynomial asymptotes, just like we ought to teach many many things.

Comment: I am not a native English speaker and I'm having a question concerning the word "slant". As far as I understand, this means "straight (or linear) but not horizontal nor vertical". However, I have the impression that you are not taking about "slant" asymptotes, but generally straight or linear ones, as in opposed to non-linear ones. Am I right or does the word "slant" also mean "linear" (including horizontal and/or vertical)?

Comment: @Dominique yes, "slant" means straight/linear but not horizontal or vertical. It's clear to me why we teach horizontal and vertical asymptotes. My question was about why many resources take it further and cover slant asymptotes, but then abruptly stop there instead of continuing onward to the general case of polynomial asymptotes.

Comment: @JustinSkycak: I believe it's the idea that you might sketch difficult graphs using some simple straight lines: imagine a graph where you have calculated four asymptotes ($y=0$, $x=0$, $x=2$ and $y=x$). You can use a simple ruler for drawing those asymptotes and the graph itself can easily be sketched, based on those simple straight lines.

Comment: Side note to your linked notes: You make it sound as if a rational function whose numerator has a smaller degree than its denominator has no horizontal asymptotes. That's not true, its h.a. is $y=0$. Just pointing it out because I just let my Precalculus class do an example of that kind and not many, but a few them claimed the function has "no" h.a.

Comment: By the way, I touch on "polynomial asymptotes" (I call them asymptotic polynomials) briefly in that chapter, but not a lot, for reasons pointed out in answers. I do show them what you call "proper form" with its "polynomial part" and "remainder". The remainder always has a h.a. $y=0$. In my eyes this is the best motivation for polynomial division. (Your "proper form" IS how the result of polynomial division should be written, and is written in Europe AFAIK.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is just that the related concepts encompassed by little-$o$ and big-$O$ notation are more important than "polynomial asymptotes" and do find many applications. We do teach Landau notation in analysis, computer science, etc.

When we talk about asymptotics, we typically reference just the dominant term. For examples, if a function is $O(n^2+n)$ then it is $O(n^2)$.

I remember when I first taught college algebra after my PhD. I don't think I had ever encountered slant asymptotes in graduate studies, and I embarrassed myself in front of that class many years ago by saying that if $y=x+1$ is a slant asymptote then saying that $y=x$ is also a slant asymptote is equally correct. But of course I was confusing the statement that $O(x+1)$ and $O(x)$ are the same with the more geometrical notion of a unique slant asymptotes.

It also occurs to me that in algebra, meaning the world of polynomials and rational functions, the notion of a polynomial asymptote is not very helpful since it says nothing about polynomials. It does have some teeth with rational functions, but then with rational functions we typically focus only on "end behavior." For example, we look at $y=\frac{x^2+1}{x+1}$ and see that it behaves like $y=x$ at infinity, and don't bother with the refinement that it behaves more like $x-1$.

Comment: Thanks, this is convincing to me. Before reading this answer, the most promising hypothesis was that "it's less useful in practice than it is in theory," and this answer points out that there's actually not much theory that builds on it, whereas there is more theory that builds on related topics of little-o and big-O notation. So if you start with polynomial asymptotes and follow that line of thought deeper, you end up at little-o and big-O notation, for which polynomial asymptotes are not actually a prerequisite.

Answer (score 5):

This is kind of a joke answer, but in my [favorite math story ever](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.physics.research/c/aiMUJrOjE8A/m/jGy2N3IaajwJ) we have the following exchange:

> Eric pondered a moment. "But... but if it's *that* simple, why
> don't my textbooks talk about it?"
>
> Grinning evilly, the Wiz replied: "They certainly drop the
> necessary clues. As for why they don't *emphasize* this stuff,
> well, this is just one of those tricks we Wizards use to distinguish
> the people who think for themselves from those who fall for any
> plausible line of claptrap. In fact, every time Halloween falls
> on a full moon - like this year - we get together and agree on
> what facts like this we will keep secret, precisely to see who
> rediscovers it for themselves. This year we...." At this point
> the absent-minded Wiz caught himself. "Whoops! This is too
> secret for you! Anyway, you just failed one of these tests."

I certainly enjoyed discovering polynomial asymptotes as a high school student, and it looks like several people in the comments to the OP did as well.

Maybe it has not made its way into the standard curriculum because it is not essential to any further coursework, but is "low hanging" enough that talented students get to discover it for themselves.  The marginal utility of introducing it to the curriculum is negative since:

1. Students who don't care about math will not be excited by one more thing to memorize, so less utils for them.
2. Students who do care about math will get less utils out of it when presented as "known math" vs. if they discover it for themselves.

Answer (score 0):

1. For issue 1, I suspect that it is just an issue of time benefit, like we could think of many enrichments.   I don't think it is an issue of nobody thought of it. Probably also contributing are the issues that the solutions are not a simple generalization of the line assymptote finding.

   It may not be exactly be in analytic geometry class, but I do think students look at this behavior in calculus and natural sciences. So, the limit of x plus e to the x is e to the x for instance, as x grows large. Also in ODEs there is some looking at solutions that we can't express analytically but that we can bound or show approaching curves.

   Possibly another issue is drawing the parabola or what have you that is the limit curve. The whole point of curve sketching is to abstract a few features, intercepts snd assymptotes snd symmetry snd the like, that allow sketching a curve without just plotting z gazillion points. But if your bounding limit is a parabola, to use it well, you'd need to have a good sketch of the parabola itself.  Very different than physically drawing a dashed line on graph paper with a straight edge.
2. I'm not so sure about the term  polynomial assymptote being appropriate. If you look at the wiki article on assymptores they talk about curve assymptotes. And you think of hyperbolic or exponentials or trig functions or the like that we might approach with given expressions.  Anyhow, I would loosen up the search terms and see what you get.

P.s.  Just sharing a few thoughts, not a definitive answer, so mods feel free to commentize, although really the question is multifaceted.  And honestly I chafe at the whole idea of lock and key answers and a semantic web. Think forum style discussion is a feature not a bug.

Answer (score 0):

A guess: Could it be a matter of time constraints? Thoroughly covering all potential outcomes and their implications is a time-intensive endeavor.